# Regular Expression Validator: Client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Here is the code for my regular expression on my aspx.cs page. The issue I am having is that when I use the same regular expression, ^\p{L}$ , in the regular expression validatdor on my aspx page, it doesn't work. Is there something different between regular expression validators and a regular expression pattern int the code behind?

```
    public static bool IsNameValid(string name)
    {
        string regExPattern = @"(^[\p{L}]$)";

        if ((!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(name, regExPattern)) || name.Length > 50)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Put te same regex "(^[\p{L}]$)" in  a RegularExpressionValidator  and i think it works for me. 
Remember that que RegularExpressionValidator in html generate a javascript validator, maybe you have some error in the JS? Try to see in firebug (or other debugger) if are any error in javascript console.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.